# 'tuple' object has no attribute 'get' Django, how i can fix this?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

[image]

view.py

```
from django.views.generic import ListView
from .models import post
# Create your views here.

class HomePageView(ListView):
    model = post
    template_name = 'home.html'
    context_object_name = 'all_posts_list'
```

i'm beginner, just start learning django framework

Comment: There is some information missing from what you've posted - either another view, or some custom middleware that is causing this. Edit your post with the exact code that reproduces the issue.